# Enabling perspective CSS transform in Chrome?

Tags: css, 3d, cross-browser, transform, webkit-transform

When I use this style with #board(the gray one)

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(45deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(45deg);
```

What it looks in Firefox:
[image: Click me to see the picture(Sorry that I am a new user.)]

But in chrome:
[image: Click me to see the picture]

What we need is the one in Firefox. So what should we do to have same look in chrome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally it's best practice to place the `perspective` on a containing element, such as the `body` or a wrapping `div`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/amustill/Qh8YV/

```
body {
    -webkit-perspective: 500px;
       -moz-perspective: 500px;
    }

div {
    ...
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateX(45deg);
    }
```

Comment: Dear @amustill , thanks for answer my question. I've tried it in Firefox and in Chrome. It still works well in Firefox, but **displays only a rectangle in chrome**.(What I want is a trapezium-like view.)

Comment: @TangentChang Which version of Chrome are you using? I'm seeing the expected and same results in both Firefox and Chrome. This syntax should work as far back as Firefox 10 and Chrome 12.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.56 m, the latest one.

Comment: @TangentChang So you don't see something like this? http://i.imgur.com/5pQc7UP.png I'm using the exact same version of Chrome.

Comment: I don't see that but a rectangle.

Comment: @TangentChang That's very strange. I've added in a little support detection. Can you test this link? http://jsfiddle.net/Qh8YV/2/ What does it say?

Comment: I've just searched for this problem. I found that maybe the problem is at GPU, since it shows "3D CSS: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable".

Comment: It says that 3D transforms are not supported.

Comment: @TangentChang I see. Having searched myself, it seems that simply re-installing Chrome is a potential 'fix'. I assume you located the diagnostic in Chrome's `about:flags` page?

Comment: I used `about:GPU`, and I think that maybe the problem is caused by the graphics driver.